# Getting Text from TextField in CodeName One for Java

Tags: java, mobile, codenameone, textfield

I have designed the GUI elements and put everything together using CodeName One plugin for Netbeans 8.1. I am first working on my client information GUI that has textfields and a submit button. I'm looking to retrieve the textfield imputs via the submit button action event(I will use the first name textfield as an example:

```
@Override
protected void onAddRecordGUI_SubmitButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    ..I tried this
    String Fname = findTxt_Firstn(c).getText();

    ..I also tried this
    String FirstName = findTxt_Firstn.getText();

    ..I then tried this
    String FirstName = Txt_Firstn.getText();


}
```

I get "error: cannot find symbol" with regards to the textfields name (It is correct and located on the same form the button is located)

Am I doing something very wrong here? I found two post on Stack, however, I tried the solutions above anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! I have solved my own questions and this might be applicable to anyone else who encounters this issue. The issue isn't the code, but it is naming textfields with an underscore "_". I renamed the field and was able to create a reference to it.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest migrating to the new GUI builder as the old GUI builder might be probleamtic,,,